# Facebook Analytics have been loading for 30 minutes now

Tags: facebook-analytics

I have just tried to set up Facebook Analytics for one of my pixels.

Yet, it doesn't finish loading. All i see is [this loading screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XnS1.png).
It have been loading for half an hour now.

Is there something wrong? I have tried in Firefox too, but it doesn't seem like its working.

Answer (score 0):

It's back up now. Looks like the engineering team saw your message.